# Controling css order

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

In my plugin I need to load css file after the standard style.css. I tried to do that with the priority paramter in the enqueue command but that works only if I modify the specificity of the classes(which is not what I want).
Is there any solution?
Regards
I. Sher

Comment: Do your theme's style.css is enqueued with a proper handle? If so, then you have to add that handle as a dependency argument in wp_enqueue_style().

Comment: Thx
The plugin should be available for any theme, so is there a way to get this handle dynamycally?

Comment: Regardless of the order your files appear in the header, if your CSS is less specific then the more specific rules in the earlier file will still have an impact

Comment: Do you want to load your css file right after theme's style.css or will it also work if your css file loads after all the stylesheets have been loaded?

Comment: Please **do not** use multiple accounts. Please merge your accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your plugin files.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_footer', 'styles_at_extremely_end_of_the_page', PHP_INT_MAX);
function styles_at_extremely_end_of_the_page() {
    ?>
    <style>
        /* Your Custom CSS here */
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I tried, This is working.Is there any way to use an already existing file?